# .htaccess redirect same domain with language parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

first of all thank you to take a little time to read my question.

I have a webpage that I need to redirect everyone who joins on it(and loads the index.php file) to the same file with parameter.

For example, If i have `www.url.com`, I want to create a rule in `.htaccess` that automatically redirected to `www.url.com/en/`.
Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$  /en [R=301,L]
```

It checks if requested path is `/`, if so then it redirects to `/en`

Comment: Yeah that is! Thank you!